# Is it possible to render $\LaTeX$ in Safari?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions, latex

Is there a Safari extension for rendering LaTeX in webpages? That is, take expressions like `$...$` and replace them in the page with the rendered LaTeX.

I couldn’t find anything on Google.

Comment: stackexchange sites that allow Latex, such as math.se, use something called MathJax.  But it runs on the server side, not just in the browser.  See http://www.mathjax.org

Comment: I know it, but i want extension that will render all expressions like $...$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven’t tried them, but there are some bookmarklets written by a user on the Mathematics Stack Exchange which sound like they do roughly what you’d want:  [Should chat have TeX support?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1088/24160)

In particular, the “render MathJax” bookmarklet sounds exactly like what you want:

> **render MathJax** installs MathJax and renders $\LaTeX$ once per execution. This is intended for use on web pages where the contents of the page are static.

These were originally written for Math.se users to get MathJax rendering in their chatroom within SE spending development time adding it to chat, but I see no reason why it wouldn’t work on an arbitrary webpage (and indeed, it seems to work like that [on the installation page](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html)).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's not plugin of Tex rendering for Safari. Only for Google Chrome and for Firefox Mozilla. There's GmailTeX, a plugin for Gmail in Chrome. If you want to have it for Safari, you need to contact the author of that plugin and persuade him to build it for Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post might be a bit dated, but if you're looking for a Gmail solution on Safari, you can use my extension https://github.com/w-woloszyn/GMTeX. It's quite basic, so if you can, using a Chrome extension would be better. However, if you must use Safari, this should work just fine!